# Replacing a H19 headlight?

Tags: headlight, kia, led, soul

On my 2020 Kia Soul S the headlight (high/low) is a H19 bulb. When I look for (LED) replacement bulbs I can't really find any—the H category doesn't seem to go up to 19. What's going on here? Is my thinking right or what seems to be the right bulb for my application?

Below is an image of the bub and from the user manual. [image: (12644LL)]

[image: User Manual]

Comment: I've changed your question a little bit so it doesn't get closed as a shopping question. Trying to find parts for your vehicle is off-topic for the site.

Comment: As of right now, H19 is Kia a specific bulb. I found a little information about it [on this webesite](https://toplight-italia.com/en/h18-and-h19/).

Comment: Thanks @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 for the info. I wonder why they went with something proprietary only on two trims of one car.

Comment: It appears the H19 is an adaptation of the H4 bulb, used because of a smaller space requirement of the bulb ... at least that was my take on it.

Comment: https://www.autozone.com/electrical-and-lighting/headlight/kia/soul

Answer (score 0):

H19 is very similar to H4 but has two extra notches.  Finding H19 is more challenging compared to the availability of H4 bulbs.  When I replaced the headlamps for Kia Sonet, I used a plier to cut the notches on the H4 bulb. This hack worked perfectly, but at the cost of a replacement warranty.  HTH.